# Route /checkout/cart/add gives 404 error after update

Tags: checkout, magento-2.1.7, m2e

After updating from **2.1.9 to 2.1.17** the **`/checkout/cart/add`** URL now responds with a 404. I checked **`.htaccess`** file, unable to find a difference.

Any ideas where this route is defined? How do I debug?

Comment: Any information in server and magento log files

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I've got the same problem.